# Animate parts of SVG with CSS on hover

Tags: svg, keyframe

I have a menu-icon in svg where I want a part of the icon to animate on hover, not the entire icon. How can I target  with a keyframe-animation when hovering the icon?

I have another menu-icon where I'm animating the entire icon on hover, but the one I'm askin here only needs one part of it to move...

Answer (score 3):

You can target inner svg elements by giving them id's and then you can select them with css.

i made this short fiddle to show how you can select the right element. i did not include keyframes because im not a animation guru with css.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z6zKd/

```
<svg width="100px" height="100px">
   <rect id="rectangle" width="100px" height="100px" fill="#000"></rect>
   <rect x="30px" id="subrectangle" width="50px" height="50px" fill="#DDD"></rect>
</svg>
```

css:

```
svg:hover #subrectangle{
   transform: rotate(60deg);
   transition: all 0.5s;
   fill: #FFF;
   left: 50px;
}
```